# What idea/field in electronics is revolutionary nowadays

Tags: theory

i realize that back then in the 30's-40's Von Neumann architecture was revolutionary, parallel at MIT, information and communication theory, and vacuum tubes were revolutionary fields, in the 70's solid state, VLSI, microelectronics, was revolutionary, 80's and 90's with networks, digital communications hardware, internet, massive programming languages, and computer architecture, were revolutionary. Now days, what are the leading areas in electronics, if you know at least one, what researcher institutes or universities are leading those advances. This question is with the purpose of a get an original idea for a research that can expand electronics.

I must concrete myself, i am looking for theoretical stuff, not practical stuff

Thank you very much

Comment: This question is not a good fit for the site because it "will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: There's a large area of bleeding-edge research that overlaps with physics and materials science. Novel semiconductors (alternatives to Si and GaAs?); novel use of photolithography to produce nanostructures; memristors and other alternative memory systems; graphene and its applications; novel bandgap materials (e.g the long search for the blue LED).

Comment: When research is happening you often dont know what will be ground breaking until you completely change things and find out you were on the path. It is easy to identify now what was ground breaking then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not wishing to cover ground mentioned by Matt (although this may be difficult), medical electronics leading to greater body part replacements could be considered. Matt mentioned nanoelectronics and this, I'm sure wil play a big role. Tapping into the brain would be a massive (and probably quite dangerous but rewarding) enterprise. "We're all gonna end up like the Borg" maybe I heard someone shout via my bionic ears. Keeping mother earth up to speed with ozone production - maybe brainstorm how electronics can work here? I'm not saying it can; but I don't think anyone can say it can't - revolutionary new electronic developments may be brought about.

But, is electronics now just a means to an end - telephony and radio can't exist without electronics but did your average victorian ever concern themselves that writing letters would become a thing of the past. How many would have predicted the commuications avalanche we have today. Has electronics had it's day - In terms of functionality and performance for "non-grunt" solutions, electronics wipes the floor with "mechanics" and, of course, in many applications, software wipes the floor with electronics.

But, where does electronics still stand head-and-shoulders above software - maybe this will point to where electronics may continue to be revolutionary?

Answer (score 1):

Read some IEEE publications. A few big fields are communication signal processing, nanoelectronics, and sustainable energy. There are tons of them. Another area that is going to be huge is biomedical devices. I read a paper a while back where someone figured that with all the baby boomers aging, we don't have nearly enough hospital and nursing home beds for all those people. More people are going to be staying in their homes longer, and there will be lots of patents on remote health monitoring technology.

The majority of current bleeding edge research is nontrivial stuff that damn near takes a Ph.d to understand. No offense, but based on your questions, I think a ground breaking study is out of your, and my, league right now. If research is your thing, find a faculty member whose work interests you, and try to work in their lab.